# Inconsistent behavior on different servers

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This is perplexing: I have an entity with string properties and I am trying to store CJK and Unicode characters.

The column data type is `nvarchar(max)`.

In the staging, local and uat environment, when I add Unicode characters, the model is saved successfully to the database.

In production, when I add Unicode characters to any property, `SaveChanges` is called successfully, but changes are not saved to the database. However when I make changes without Unicode characters, the changes are saved to the database.

For the production server, I can insert Unicode characters using SSMS and SQL commands. So the database can store Unicode characters.

What could be the reason?

In all instances, the call to `SaveChanges` returns 1.

Should I just give up and use Dapper or something?

```
var email = await context.Emails.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID = emailId);

if (email == null) 
    return false

// this is the string property
// entity.Property(e => e.Body)
        .IsRequired()
        .IsUnicode(true)

// this wont get saved to database but save changes return 1
email.Body = "  "
// this will get saved to the database
// email.Body = "hello world"

var changes = await context.SaveChangesAsync();

return changes > 0
    ? true
    : false
```

Comment: There's no reason it should not work in production. Start by checking the differences. How have the servers + db been configured? Are they the same versions? Are they docker images created from same template? Check the db collation settings, the versions of os.

Comment: The uat and production are using the same type of aws instance and sql server. If I run the commands directly in ssms, the changes are made.

Comment: Maybe check the "Debug" / "Release" configuration ? like use the Release build configuration for a dev, if that difference is relevant for your setup. Could also clone the production environment to experiment the other way round.